# One Id of composite key to be referenced in another entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

- Table 1 has only two columns which form a composite key.
- Table 2 id column is being generated.
- Value for one property of Table1 I am supplying and for second property I need it to pick up the generated value of Table2.
  Here is what I have so far-

Composite primary key:

```
public class PKClass implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2092390836751020965L;
    public PKClass(){}
    public PKClass(long actId, long actAttId){
        this.actvId = actId;
        this.actvAtId = actAttId;
    }

    private long actvId;
    private long actvAtId;
    // getters, setters, equals, hashcode
}
```

Entity class 1:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "Table1")
@IdClass(PKClass.class)
public class AtLinkData implements Serializable
{
    @Id @Column(name = "ACT_ID", nullable = false)
    private long actvId;
    @Id @Column(name = "ACT_AT_ID")
    private long actvAtId;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, , mappedBy = "atLinkData")
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACT_AT_ID")
    private AtData atData;
    // getters, setters
}
```

Entity class 2:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "Table2")
public class AtData implements Serializable
{
    @TableGenerator(name = "somename", table = "sometable", pkColumnName = "somecolumn", valueColumnName = "valuename", pkColumnValue = "Table2", allocationSize = 1)
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "somename")
    @Column(name = "ACT_AT_ID")
    private Long id;
    // other variables
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACT_AT_ID")
    private AtLinkData atLinkData;
    // getters setters
}
```

I have been trying different things, but with the code above, I am getting the error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: broken column mapping for: atLinkData.id of: com.test.database.AtData
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved it:

AtLinkData.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "foreignGenerator")
@org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name = "foreignGenerator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "atData"))
@Column(name = "ACT_AT_ID")
private long actvAtId;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "ACT_AT_ID",insertable=false,updatable=false)
private AtData atData;
// getters, setters
```

AtData.java

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="atData")
private AtLinkData atLinkData;
```

Thanks [@CycDemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1573835/cycdemo) for your help.

Answer (score 5):

@OneToOne(mappedBy="otherInfo")
Use `JoinColumns` annotation not `JoinColumn`.

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACTVID", referencedColumnName = "ACTVID"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACTVATID", referencedColumnName = "ACTVATID")
})
private AtLinkData atLinkData;
```

DB table of `AtData` entity you have to add two foreign key column `ACTVID` and `ACTVATID`.

**Update**

If you cannot add new columns in `Table 2`, use `mappedBy` attribute at `AtData` entity, not `AtLinkData`. Try as below.

AtLinkData.java

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "ACT_AT_ID")
private AtData atData;
```

AtData.java

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="atData")
private AtLinkData atLinkData;
```

Comment: I can not add another column in Table 2, it is an existing table.

Comment: Changed code as suggested, now code is failing because actvAtId in PKClass is null and hence, hashcode() is failing. Am I supposed to instantiate PKClass inside AtLinkData? From what I know, I guess not. :/
Now, entity AtData is being persisted successfully if I try separately.