# Hibernate: Facing "broken column mapping for id" using composite key referenced in another entity

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm facing problem in creating one to one mapping in Hibernate. Following is how i'm trying to achieve it.

Following is my super class for SysEntity

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseSysEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@Column(name="sysupdate")
private Date sysupdate;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Date getSysupdate() {
    return sysupdate;
}

public void setSysupdate(Date sysupdate) {
    this.sysupdate = sysupdate;
}

}
```

Following class is the entity which will create oneToOne relation ship with "Project"

```
@Entity
@Table(name="sysproject")
public class SysProject extends BaseSysEntity implements Serializable {

@OneToOne(optional=true, fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="sysClientId", referencedColumnName="sysClientId"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="pProject", referencedColumnName="pProject")
})
private Project project;

public Project getProject() {
    return project;
}

public void setProject(Project project) {
    this.project = project;
}
}
```

Following is Project class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tproject")
public class Project {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ProjectID id; // It contains sysClientId and pProject as primary key
    @OneToOne(optional=true, mappedBy="project")
    private SysProject SysProject;

}
```

ProjectID Class:

```
@Embeddable
public class ProjectID implements Serializable{

@Column(name="pProject")
private String project;

@Column(name="sysClientId")
private String sysClientId;

public String getProject() {
    return project;
}

public ProjectID(){
    this.sysClientId="0";
}

public ProjectID(Integer number){
    this();
    this.project = number.toString();
}

public void setProject(String project) {
    this.project = project;
}

public String getSysClientId() {
    return sysClientId;
}

public void setSysClientId(String sysClientId) {
    this.sysClientId = sysClientId;
}
}
```

Exception which i'm getting:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: broken column mapping for: SysProject.id of: com.spin.integration.dto.Project
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.initPropertyPaths(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:178)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.initIdentifierPropertyPaths(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:249)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.initPropertyPaths(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:222)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.initOrdinaryPropertyPaths(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2434)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.initPropertyPaths(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2471)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.postConstruct(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3766)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:451)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:163)
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:386)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1790)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
... 18 more
```

NOTE: This oneToOne mapping is not present at database level (Unfortunately i can't make changes to database).

Comment: No it didn't worked. Now it is giving error: No identifier specified for entity: com.spin.integration.dto.SysProject

Comment: facing Same Error: No identifier specified for entity: com.spin.integration.dto.SysProject

Comment: acing Same Error: No identifier specified for entity: com.spin.integration.dto.SysProject

Comment: canu post ur ProjectID class code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252080/one-id-of-composite-key-to-be-referenced-in-another-entity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check this solution its working :
[One Id of composite key to be referenced in another entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252080/one-id-of-composite-key-to-be-referenced-in-another-entity)
he's facing the same issue

```
@OneToOne(optional=true, fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="sysClientId", referencedColumnName="sysClientId"),
    @JoinColumn(name="pProject", referencedColumnName="pProject")
})
```

Comment: Instead of using PrimaryKeyJoinColumns I had to use JoinColumns.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using @PrimaryKeyJoinColumns I had to use @JoinColumns.